# Allocate Memory for SBT command

Tags: sbt

The sbt run and the command seems to be slower in execution. I have unused 10gb of ram which i can use

Please advise on how to specify memory for SBT command line

Thanks

Comment: `sbt --help` is your what you need. If you do it, you'll find `--mem` option that can be used as `sbt --mem 4096`, ie allocate 4GB of memory. It uses 1GB by default. Also, your performance problem may not be related to lack of memory

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Thanks a lot. So what are the usual check points other than the above.  May be any comments like expert from you would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Environment Variable In Windows**

```
Key - SBT_OPTS
Value - -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xmx2G
```

**Bash Profile In Linux**

```
.bash_profile
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx1536M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
         -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M  -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

**Command Line Option**

```
 sbt -mem 4096, ie allocate 4GB of memory
```

**SBT_OPTS**

```
SBT_OPTS environment variable, if unset uses "$default_sbt_opts". Example

SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx3536M -Xss1M 
         -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
         -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=724M"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer where you can commit a file into the repo create `.jvmopts` and populate, for example with:

```
-Xmx8G
-Xss16M
-Xms2048M
```

Then if you want to check that you have set correctly run `sbt -verbose`